# Github organization management

Tags: git, github

I have the following situation: I have 4 teams eager to contribute to an open source project. The teams are in the form of organizations. I have created an intermediary repository where I cloned the open source project. This repository was cloned by the four teams' organization. Now one team contributed something and I've made a pull request to the open source project. As I am the only owner of the intermediary repository in the commit list of the pull request only my name is clickable. The names of the others who contributed are shown next to their commits but their name is not clickable. If the pull request will be accepted will they be considered contributors? If not can you tell me how can I set up the organization in a way that their contribution will be recognized?

**UPDATE**

`ikarakatsanis` is not clickable but `aptoth` is.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is - they need to create a pull request from their team account; in order to be shown as contributors (in the sense you are talking about).

However since its an opensource project; you can easily edit the description/readme to include the appropriate names and add that as a separate pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Git has a notion of "committer" and "author". Github displays both, at least under certain circumstances. It sounds like for these commits, git recognises you as the committer but the original authors as the authors, which is correct in a sense (you are the committer because of the way you merged in their changes). I think this is right but a screenshot would help to be sure.